# Est-ce que studio est un anglicisme ?

Tags: anglicismes

Je me cherche un nom de compagnie pour pouvoir éventuellement l'enregistrer. Cependant, la loi 101 au Québec ne permet pas d'avoir un nom complètement en anglais, ce qui est difficile pour une équipe qui travaille dans le multimédia.

Je me demande donc si le mot « Studio » est considéré comme un anglicisme et ne pourrait donc pas être utilisé.

Si c'est un anglicisme, quels autres mots pourrais-je utiliser qui garderaient le même esprit ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Studio* est répertorié dans le [GDT](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/) dans le sens de [local pour la photographie](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17043120), [pour le cinéma](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8426316) ou [pour la prise de son](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=4495412), d'[agence publicitaire](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8450825), d'[entreprise de production cinéma](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=19048994), ainsi que [de logement d'une pièce](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17013357), etc. Le mot existe bel et bien en français québecois. (Au passage, il a [les mêmes sens](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/studio) en France.)

Le mot vient de l'anglais (d'où il a été importé de l'italien, qui l'a tiré du latin, qui l'a lui-même reçu de l'italique, etc.). Ce n'est pas parce qu'un mot vient d'une autre langue que ce n'est pas un mot français. *Studio* est d'ailleurs parfaitement bien intégré : il a une orthographe, une prononciation et un pluriel réguliers.

Answer (score 2):

S'il s'agit d'un studio d'enregistrement, tu peux aussi dire « Plateau », mais c'est un peu moins attrayant.

Le mot studio dans ce contexte est peut-être originellement utilisé par les anglais, mais ses origines sont latines, et je pense qu'il fait parti maintenant de la langue française aussi.